# Pass a string from CodeIgniter Controller to date_diff

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I have a loop where all the data I take from an Excel sheet returned is in date format. Here's the loop:

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= 6; $row++) {
        $cell[] = $objWorksheet->getCell($column.$row)->getFormattedValue();
    }
```

It's everything ok. I can also create a table with that data using CODEIGNITER table library. The problem now is that I need to compare that data extracted from that sheet to today date and check the days difference between data extracted to today. Have some way to do that? I tried to work with date_create($cell) but that function didn't accept array. And I need to compare all dates of array each one to today.

**Edit**:

Hi, I'm trying to compare 2 dates with date_diff, but the date2 is a string that comes from a controller in my CodeIgniter.

```
$date1 = date_create("today");

        foreach ($dashboardSheetData as $date) {
            $date2 = strtotime($date);
            $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
            echo $diff->format("%a");
        }
```

I need to make date_diff between $date1 and $date2, but I can't because my $date2 will be a string and it's not accepted. How can I make date_diff passing a string?

Comment: Solved the first question, question edited with the real problem

Comment: can you please var_dump() both of the dates.

Comment: @RahulM here is: string(10) "02.05.2016" string(10) "02.05.2016" string(10) "02.05.2016" string(10) "02.05.2016" string(10) "02.05.2016" object(DateTime)#109 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for this quick answer; I am not sure on what the data is looking like, however, you do want to give the date_diff parameters as YYYY-MM-DD so please be sure to format it as such.
ref: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($dashboardSheetData as $date) {
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    echo $diff->format("%a");
}
```